# inner join error at Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I would like to get matched data frpm two table. 
only matched same colume value at 'pn' display data.

I write below code.

```
$majis = St::join('sts.pn', '=', 'pn_list.pn')->get();
return view('contacts.index')->with('majis',$majis);
```

then I got this error

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sts.pn' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sts` inner join `sts`.`pn` on `=` = `pn_list`.`pn`)
```

this is my first time to use inner join. what is problem?

As tested myself I can display each tabale as separete.

Current error here

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' (SQL: select * from `sts` inner join `pn_list` on `sts`.`pn` = `pn_list`.`pn`)
```

About display. How to write tow foreach when I those 
 @foreach ($records as $record) and @foreach ($majis as $maji)  ?

current blade file

```
  @foreach ($records as $record)
        <tr>   
            <td>{{ $record->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $record->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $maji->pname }} {{ $maji->pdetail }}</td> 
            <td>{{ $record->memo }}</td>
       </tr>     
  @endforeach
```

Controller

```
$majis = St::join('pn_list', 'sts.pn', '=', 'pn_list.pn')->get();
 return view('contacts.index')->with('records',$records)->with('pn',$pn)->with('ename',$ename)->with('pns',$pns)->with('majis',$majis);
```

My goal

Main table(st) has most of data. 
 I would like to add some extra detail.
 detail are Sub table(pns) has.

Main table data are "record histroy". 
 Each record has $pn that means product number.

Sub table has these colum $Pn is product number,
 $pname is product name and $pdetail is product detail.

For example Main record $pn is 425 
 Sub table responce and display No.425's product name and detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `join()` has to be the table:

```php
$majis = St::join('pn_list', 'sts.pn', '=', 'pn_list.pn')->get();
```

Comment: Hi. @Jonas Staudenmeir  you again. Thank you for helping me. I got this error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add.  'pn_list' (SQL: select * from `pn_list` inner join `pn_list` on `sts`.`pn` = `pn_list`.`pn`)

Comment: tableA name is sts.  tableB name is pns.   colume name are same 'pn'

Comment: You are using the code from my answer? Isn't `sts` the table of the `St` model?

Comment: I'm sorry. I fixed that. now I got this error. I posted above.

Comment: As the error says, the two `pn` columns have different collations. Can you change the database or does it have to be this way?

Comment: Thank you @Jonas Staudenmeir ! you save me today too^^ some how I made diffrenct collations. I match it both then I can get a data! Thank you so much. but now I come up new problem. i will post again.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I make you confuse. I post my goal. I thought just nest 2nd foreach but it seems like went wrong i got 8000 records loop was so slow browser all most crash. I think I'm doing bad. I'm just studing code but my goal is above. Thanks again.